# circleci continuous integration rails app error require stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, circleci

I am trying to use Circleci for continuous integration and running into an issue. I am deploying a rails 4 app using ruby 2.2.2 and rspec.

When I try to push my first build through circleci I get an error when it tries to run my test suite on the line of code in my 'spec_helper' where I am requiring the stripe gem. I use stripe in the app and test it with 'stripe-mock'

The error is below. So the failure is my line `require "stripe"` in spec_helper. To be clear rspec runs and passes locally, but I get this error on circleci. I double checked and I have all my environment variables on circleci set up. I've heard that sometimes a gem needs binaries set up on circleci to work. Is this perhaps the problem? How would I do this?

```
rspec
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- stripe (LoadError)
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/propel/spec/spec_helper.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core.rb:97:in `configure'
from /home/ubuntu/propel/spec/spec_helper.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `block in requires='
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `each'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `requires='
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `block in process_options_into'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `each'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `process_options_into'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:101:in `setup'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin/rspec:23:in `load'

from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>' rspec returned exit code 1
```

I should also note that I do have stripe in my gemfile as you can see here:

```
gem 'stripe'
```

And you can see where I require stripe in my rspec spec_helper here:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

require 'stripe'
require 'stripe_mock'
require 'thin'
```

Despite having stripe in my gemfile I decided I'd try to add `sudo gem install stripe` to my `circle.yml` file to make sure it was included for testing but got the following error:

```
sudo gem install stripe
ERROR:  Error installing stripe:

sudo gem install stripe returned exit code 1

mime-types requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2. Action failed: sudo gem install stripe
```

And this is even when I specify a ruby version in my circle.yml file as 2.2.2

Comment: Do you have a Gemfile? Is the stripe gem in it? Would be best to show that. Also would be best to show the relevant bit of spec_helper.

Comment: hey @DaveSchweisguth - I do have the stripe gem in my gemfile. I've updated my answer with that info and relevant spec_helper code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `sudo gem install stripe` to your `circle.yml` file, you should add `gem stripe` to your `Gemfile`.

The [CircleCI documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/manually#dependencies) says:

> In all likelihood, you'll have a list of libraries and dependencies that your app requires. CircleCI automatically detects Ruby's Gemfile, … and then runs the appropriate commands to install the dependencies.

If you don't already have a `Gemfile`, you can:

1. Run `gem install bundler`.
2. Create a `Gemfile` listing the Rubygems your application needs to run, including `stripe`. It should look something like this:

   ```
   source "https://rubygems.org"
   gem "stripe"
   ```
3. Run the `bundle` command. This should create a `Gemfile.lock` file, listing specific versions of the gems you use that are compatible with each other.
4. Commit bot the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` to your version control system.

The [Bundler Web site](http://bundler.io/) has a lot more [information about Gemfiles](http://bundler.io/v1.11/gemfile.html).

Comment: Thanks for reaching out @georgebrock - I do have a gem file with stripe in it. I updated my answer with some of your formatting and added some more relevant code.